# Finding the longest sub-string with no repetition in a string. Time Complexity?

Tags: performance, algorithm, time

I recently interviewed with a company for software engineering position. I was asked the question of longest unique sub-string in a string. My algorithms was as follows -

Start from the left-most character, and keep storing the character in a hash table with the key as the `character` and the value as the `index_where_it_last_occurred`. Add the character to the answer string as long as its not present in the hash table. If we encounter a stored character again, I stop and note down the length. I empty the hash table and then start again from the right index of the repeated character. The right index is retrieved from the (index_where_it_last_occurred) flag. If I ever reach the end of the string, I stop and return the longest length.

For example, say the string was, `abcdecfg`.

I start with `a`, store in hash table. I store `b` and so on till `e`. Their indexes are stored as well. When I encounter `c` again, I stop since it's already hashed and note down the length which is 5. I empty the hash table, and start again from the right index of the repeated character. The repeated character being `c`, I start again from the position 3 ie., the character `d`. I keep doing this while I don't reach the end of string.

I am interested in knowing what the time complexity of this algorithm will be. IMO, it'll be O(n^2).

This is the code.

```
import java.util.*;
public class longest
{
    static int longest_length = -1;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = in.nextLine();
        calc(str,0);    
        System.out.println(longest_length);
    }

    public static void calc(String str,int index)
    {
        if(index >= str.length()) return;
        int temp_length = 0;
        LinkedHashMap<Character,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Character,Integer>();
        for (int i = index; i<str.length();i++) 
        {
            if(!map.containsKey(str.charAt(i)))
            {
                map.put(str.charAt(i),i);
                ++temp_length;
            }
            else if(map.containsKey(str.charAt(i)))
            {
                if(longest_length < temp_length)
                {
                    longest_length = temp_length;
                }
                int last_index = map.get(str.charAt(i));
//              System.out.println(last_index); 
                calc(str,last_index+1);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(longest_length < temp_length)
            longest_length = temp_length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about that problem statement?  The longest unique substring would be the entire string (it only occurs once).  If you're restricted to proper substrings, then in nearly all cases, the entire string without its first or last character will be optimal.  The only case where this doesn't hold is when the string consists of repeats of a single character: in this case, there are no unique proper substrings.

Comment: I think the question is about finding a substring in which no character appears more than once. I agree that it's unclear.

Comment: This can be done in O(n) time. Whenever a repetition occurs, do not empty it completely, just save the length and advance the left index.

Comment: Sorry if the question was unclear. It is indeed finding the longest substring with no repetition.

Answer (score 1):

If the alphabet is of size K, then when you restart counting you jump back at most K-1 places, so you read each character of the string at most K times. So the algorithm is O(nK).

The input string which contains n/K copies of the alphabet exhibits this worst-case behavior. For example if the alphabet is {a, b, c}, strings of the form "abcabcabc...abc" have the property that nearly every character is read 3 times by your algorithm.

You can solve the original problem in O(K+n) time, using O(K) storage space by using dynamic programming.

Let the string be `s`, and we'll keep a number M which will be the the length of maximum unique_char string ending at i, P, which stores where each character was previously seen, and `best`, the longest unique-char string found so far.

Start:

```
Set P[c] = -1 for each c in the alphabet.
M = 0
best = 0
```

Then, for each i:

```
M = min(M+1, i-P[s[i]])
best = max(best, M)
P[s[i]] = i
```

This is trivially O(K) in storage, and O(K+n) in running time.